# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to seed UserRole in my ASP.NET Core MVC App, but it's throwing the following exception.

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
>   An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.AspNetRoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.

## Add service

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(option =>
               option.UseSqlServer(
               Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options => { });
```

## Seed

```
private void CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<SchoolUser>>();
        .................
        .................
}
```

I'm calling the `CreateRoles()`inside the `Configure()` of Startup.cs
and it throwing the above exception at first line of the `CreateRoles()`. 
Exception saying that it's DependencyInjection problem, how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're intending to use Entity Framework Core for your ASP.NET Core Identity persistence, but you haven't quite set this up yet. `IRoleStore` et al are not registered by default, as this is an extension point to allow for different persistence mechanisms to be used. In order to use EF core here, you just need to add a call to [`AddEntityFrameworkStores`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityentityframeworkbuilderextensions.addentityframeworkstores?view=aspnetcore-2.1), like so:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 4):

According the MSDN document, most effective way is

```
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>() <--Here!!!
     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get this error if you don't create the scope for your DI.

Assuming you seed in your `Program.cs`

```
var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

try
{
    var scope = host.Services.CreateScope(); <-- Need this

    var roleMgr = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

host.Run();
```