# Why the identity implementation in .NET 7 has errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I want to create a .NET 7 project with clean architecture([JasonTaylor](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture))

When I run the program, I get this error:

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.)

I have two general questions:

- Why do I get this error?
- And after that, running the context factory is the right thing to do?

My source code - `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// *** CustomConfiguration
builder.Services.InfrastructureServices(builder.Configuration);
// *** CustomConfiguration
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Custom class for registering service in infrastructure layer:

```
namespace Infrastructure.Configuration
{
    public static class ConfigurationInfrastructure
    {
        public static IServiceCollection InfrastructureServices
        (this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataBaseContext>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(option =>
            {
                option.UseSqlServer();
            });
            services.AddScoped<ISqlServer>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<DataBaseContext>());
            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

Because I implemented the services in the infrastructure layer, I encountered the problem of instantiating from the context, so I found the implementation of this solution by searching on Google.

```
namespace Infrastructure.Context
{
    public class ContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DataBaseContext>
    {
        public DataBaseContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            IConfigurationBuilder builder =
                new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(path)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
            string? connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStringName");
            DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataBaseContext> dbContextOptionsBuilder =
                new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataBaseContext>();
            if (connectionString != null) DataBaseContext.AddBaseOptions(dbContextOptionsBuilder, connectionString);
            return new DataBaseContext(dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

Because I don't have a service(Interface Or Service), I don't know why the error occurs.

Thank you for guiding me

Comment: can u delete my answer.  use this comment services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>(); this is the full answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53470623/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-irolestore/53471260#53471260

Answer (score 0):

I think `AddDbContext` should be on top of the `AddIdentityCore` because the `AddIdentityCore` depends on `AddDbContext`.

So your `ConfigurationInfrastructure` will look like this :

```
namespace Infrastructure.Configuration
{
    public static class ConfigurationInfrastructure
    {
        public static IServiceCollection InfrastructureServices
        (this IServiceCollection services,
            IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(option =>
            {
                option.UseSqlServer();
            });
            services.AddScoped<ISqlServer>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<DataBaseContext>());
            services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataBaseContext>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            return services;
        }
    }
}
```